# Connecting alerts and SIEM with Microsoft Graph data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

Is there any guidance for integrating my SIEM (security information and event management system with) Microsoft Graph to connect my security alerts with other Microsoft Graph entities?

Comment: Microsoft Graph integration docs are located here (http://graph.microsoft.com/docs). Nothing out there about security or SIEMs, but I believe there will be something announced eminently.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Graph integration docs are located [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview). Currently there is no documentation out there about security or SIEMs, but I believe there will be something announced eminently.

Comment: The Graph Security API team released documentation on SIEM integration through Azure Monitor using an event hub (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/security_siemintegration). It walks through Splunk integration, but Azure Monitor supports other SIEM. as well, so the same event hub solution applies to all supported SIEMs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs#what-can-i-do-with-the-monitoring-data-being-sent-to-my-event-hub).

Answer (score 0):

I've published a cross-platform solution into GitHub (https://github.com/tamhinsf/AzureMonitor4Siem) that includes instructions and a script to automate the setup of the Azure Monitor -> Event Hub data pipeline, and a cross-platform .NET Core-based application that connects to Event Hub to download the Azure activities sent to it.

You can use it as a simple solution to perform a file-based integration with a SIEM of your choice.

Additionally, it's another path to validate Graph Security driven alerts into the Monitor -> Event Hub pipeline.